# Durandal js and Facebook client side authentication

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, durandal

I am not able to figure out how do I use facebook's client side authentication with Durandal.js. Can someone provide me with some example of something?

I tried to initialize facebook's authentication on view attached of my home view but that just doesn't work. It returns undefined user's name, although it launches facebook's login popup and closes it when I am logged in but it just doesn't returns me any response.

Comment: What are you using aswell as durendal ?

Answer (score 0):

For Durandal authentication, check out: https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth